# Can I use MemoryMappedFiles with images

Tags: c#, virtual-memory

I am just curious about this.  As I understand it memorymappedfiles are files stored in virtual memory.

Now I have this scenario.. 
I have a usercontrol in a winform c# application.
I have a static bitmap object declared in this usercontrol.
I am getting a new image file (same format and size) 8 times a second.
I update the static bitmap file with the new image as it comes in.
I override the onpaint in my usercontrol to display the image.

Is there any milage in using a memorymapped file/object instead of the static bitmap object to improve upon memory usage?

I have never worked with it before and I cannot find much about it especially in this situation..

thanks

Comment: The Bitmap class, through GDI+, already uses a memory mapped file.  So no, pretty unlikely how you could do better.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That was the clarification I needed.  I would have given u a 'tick' if i could. Thanks again!